Sources for halachic advice on sensory issues/autistic traits in relation to marital intimacy
Autism is quite common and higher functioning autism may be undiagnosed for many years.  It is also possible for some people to have some autistic traits.  In the context of marriage, this can be difficult due to various problems, including a lack of desire for physical affection and intimacy and/or sensory issues which can make it feel unpleasant (although not in all cases - everyone is different).  Such individuals may consider themselves perfectly normal and eg. believe that the whole point in marriage is to raise a good Jewish family.  They may think that the whole idea of thinking of their spouse in terms of physical desire is disgusting and not something they want to try to achieve.
As well as making מצות relating to intimacy difficult, it can be difficult for the spouse to cope with the lack of affection and physical desire from an emotional perspective.  These issues can affect men and women.
Are there any ספרים (preferably in English) which deal with these sorts of issues?  Ideally something which lays out what is normal in a Jewish marriage in fairly explicit unambiguous terms so that an autistic person can understand that what their spouse wants is in line with הלכה and Jewish thought?
Are there any רבנים who can be contacted (preferably anonymously) for more specific advice?
Are there any services who can help with these issues?

This really isn't a question for this site because a) it really needs to be dealt with on a case by case, personal basis, b) needs involvement from professionals, as it would be wrong to make assumptions without discussing with therapists and/or medical doctors. There could be many factors involved and it needs a holistic approach.

Agreed. Find a marriage counselor and a mental-health professional who specialize in autistic/sensory issues. If you're concerned that anything they say is against halacha, find a competent rabbi and loop him in to the conversation. I wouldn't go to the Judaica store looking for a book on lawnmower repair. (And if someone eventually put one out, it would basically be repackaging some outside book on lawnmower repair, then adding in a couple of inspirational quotes from Jewish sources.)

Or try emailing yoatzot.org
